# Set embed title to a clickable link

Tags: javascript, node.js, url, discord.js

I have a [RichEmbed](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RichEmbed) and I want to make it so I can have a field title that when I click on it, it will lead me to a link.

Answer (score 9):

If you want the title of the embed to be a link, you can add a [`.url`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RichEmbed?scrollTo=url) property to it, either by using [`RichEmbed.setURL()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RichEmbed?scrollTo=setURL), manually setting it or adding it to the object you pass in the constructor.

If you want the title of a field to be a link that can't be done since that, unfortunately, doesn't support markdown :\
If you want you can add the link in the value text of the field, using markdown:

```
embed.addField("Field title", "Your text here: [link](http://example.com)")
```

Comment: If that solved your problem, please accept the answer by clicking on the tick on the left: this will mark the question as resolved :)

Answer (score 1):

It's MessageEmbed and this is old now but:

```js
embed.setURL('url here')
```

Comment: You could improve your answer by linking to the relevant updated documentation, since the link in the question is now broken.