# Discordjs how i can send a embed message with multi link

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, embed

I want to make the embed message like the regular music bot like this embed message with the link can click

[image]

I want my content is the Description will show and the highlight is a link attach to it like the picture. and here is my embed

[image]

here's my code

```js
if (command === 'test') {

  var search = message.content.split(/\s+/g).slice(1).join(" ");
  if (!search.length) {
    return message.channel.send("PLs enter a name!");
  }
  else {
    const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(`https://i hide website cause privacy?keyword=${search}`);


    let Anime = await page.evaluate(() => {
      let items = document.querySelectorAll('ul[class= "last-film-box"] > li > a');
      let links = [];

      items.forEach(item => {
        links.push({
          titl: item.title,
          url: item.href

        });

      });
      return links;
    });

    let i = 0;
    let content = Anime.map(e => {
      i++;
      return i + "/ " + `${e.titl.slice(0, 50)} ${e.url}`;
    })

    let ContentEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
    ContentEmbed.setTitle("Here the result");
    ContentEmbed.setDescription(content);
    message.channel.send(ContentEmbed);

  }
}
```

Comment: Answers gave the solution but not really the reason, it's using markdown which is sort of just easy styled text, many sites use it including stackoverflow, https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set embed title to a clickable link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54134880/set-embed-title-to-a-clickable-link)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `[Video Title](Video Link)` to achieve that

```js
let content = Anime.map(e => {
  i++;
  return `${i}/ [${e.titl.slice(0, 50)}](${e.url})`;
})
```

Comment: it's very help me thanks alot i will learn it more about and learn about using markdown to

Answer (score 1):

```js
return `/`${i}/ /` [${e.titl.slice(0,50)}](${e.url})`;
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged on SO. Adding an explanation increases its long term value, and helps future visitors understand why/how it addresses the issue. This enables visitors see how they can apply this knowledge to their own issues. Words are often easier to digest than raw code, adds context, or focuses the reader to the key parts of your solution. Such answers are also more likely to be upvoted. Please consider editing, to add info or documentation links, to increase your answer's value, and keep SO Answers focused on spreading knowledge.